# Why we should pack data symbols in the band center before convolution with a lowpass filter?

Tags: finite-impulse-response, ofdm

I am investigating the spectrum shaping filter for OFDM modulation, and following an example on

https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/f-ofdm-vs-ofdm-modulation.html

In the part

> F-OFDM Transmit Processing

of the example, I could not find the reason why we have to pack data in band center, which is similar to a bandpass filter, however a lowpass filter is considered in the example.

When I pack data from the zero-th frequency (i.e., the beginning of the frequency bin array), perform convolution with the filter, and decode at receiver; I got the wrong data.

When I pack data such that data symbols occupy the band center, perform convolution with the filter, and decode at receiver; I got the correct data.

Does it means that the filter is bandpass filter and is not low pass filter?

Thank you.

Comment: this is all in baseband. What specifically do you mean when you say "bandpass filter"? A low-pass filter in baseband is of course a bandpass filter in the equivalent bandpass system, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Hi. I mean lowpass and bandpass in baseband.